# here to insert element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to insert a `div` inside the div having id = newDiv when the `<button class="songBtn btn"><i class="fa fa-play fa-lg playbtn"></i></button>` is clicked. How can I do this with jQuery? I'm using `after()` but it only inserts the div after the button.
**actually, I want to do this dynamically as there could be multiple sections like this**
here is my HTML code

```
<div class="row border-bottom g-3  player-song-detail">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-2 my-auto text-center">
      <!-- play button -->
      <button class="songBtn btn"><i class="fa fa-play fa-lg playbtn"></i></button>
      <input type="text" value="Song Title" placeholder="write song title here" hidden>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-8 my-auto" id="newDiv">
      <!-- div should be inserted here -->
    </div>       
  </div>
```

here is my jQuery code

```
 $(".songBtn").click(function(){ 
          $( this ).after( "<div>Test Div</div>" ); 
});
```

Comment: use `append` instead of `after`

Comment: actually, I want to do this dynamically as there could be multiple sections like this

Answer (score 1):

use `append` instead of `after`

```js
 $(".songBtn").click(function(){ 
          $( "#newDiv" ).append( "<div>Test Div</div>" ); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row border-bottom g-3  player-song-detail">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-2 my-auto text-center">
      <!-- play button -->
      <button class="songBtn btn"><i class="fa fa-play fa-lg playbtn"></i>btn</button>
      <input type="text" value="Song Title" placeholder="write song title here" hidden>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-8 my-auto" id="newDiv">
      <!-- div should be inserted here -->
    </div>       
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.songBtn').click(function(){
  $('#newDiv').append('<div></div>');
})
```

```css
#newDiv{
  border:1px solid red;
}
#newDiv div{
  background:orange;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:10px;height:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newDiv">This is div with ID newDiv</div>
<button class="songBtn btn">this is the button</button>
```